# Core Data document and DocumentGroup (migrating from NSPersistentDocument / UIManagedDocument)

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, swiftui

is there an easy way to use Core Data-backed document with a SwiftUI `DocumentGroup`?

My app is currently using `NSPersistentDocument` / `UIManagedDocument` and I struggle to migrate it to the new API.
Any tips appreciated :)

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I've been looking at the documentation for ReferenceFileDocument, and my hunch is that it could work if an appropriate choice for Snapshot is chosen. However I'm not sure what that should be just yet.